# Unable to upgrade from Lucid Lynx to Maverick Meerkat

Tags: 10.10, 10.04, upgrade

I have got a problem with Update Manager. I'm running Lucid Lynx ver. 10.04.2 and I'm unable to upgrade it to 10.10 version.

I have got this message when trying to upgr. :

> This can be caused by:
>
> - Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
> - Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

I couldn't accidentally download pre-released updates or unsupported updates cause both of those options stays 'unticked' in software sources/updates, so that can't be that.

EDIT: Those options stayed disable. I have never enabled them.

Unofficial software packages then? If yes, how to find which of them I have to get rid off?

My current Ubuntu version is: 10.04.2 LTS

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question _is_ on-topic for Super User; however, you're more likely to get a good response at http://askubuntu.com, the Stack Exchange site dedicated to Ubuntu problems. If you would like your question moved there, flag it for moderator attention by clicking the "flag" link, and ask for it to be migrated there. If you'd prefer for your question to remain here, then no problem. Good luck!

Comment: Migrated in AskUbuntu at the request of the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you haven't got random sources enabled doesn't mean you don't have software from them currently installed. Removing a source doesn't remove the software you obtained from it.

I suggest you take a look at the files in /var/log/dist-upgrade/ to see where things are failing.

If you can't figure it out, perhaps post them here so we can take a look.

Comment: Those options stayed disable. I have never enabled them.

Comment: I've got one problem in main log:  ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.'  Still, does not specify what package may cause this error

Comment: Ok, but I'm sure there is more information in those log files.

Comment: full log info is available here: http://justpaste.it/86n

Comment: Ok well there are references in there to deb http://falcon.landure.fr, http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu, http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ etc. etc. repositories... you **have** been using 3rd party, unsupported repositories. Packages from one of these is probably causing your problem. I also notice one of them at least is 'hardy'... not your version? Try removing all packages you've installed from these and attempting the upgrade again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. My guess would be it is that falcon.landure repository. Any hints how can I get rid of it?

Comment: As I say, removing the repository from your list of sources isn't the same as downgrading the packages you've installed from the repository... and its not easy.

Comment: Easy or not. As long as it is possible I'm willing to give it a try. I need to know where to start though.

Comment: A bit of googling suggests getting the apt-show-versions package and grepping the output from that in a few ways. e.g. removing the other repositories, then grepping apt-show-versions output for 'newer' or 'not available'

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The solution is to go into synaptic and remove the package xserver-xorg-video-nouveau. Do your upgrade as normal, then, if you need xserver-xorg-video-nouveau, re-install it. It seems to be required for nvidia graphic cards, although I don't know why it was on my system as I have a Radeon card? I left it out and my system is running ok. This problem is 718321 in Launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

If you open synaptic, click on the source button in the left. Synaptic will now list the packages from each repository. Select the needed repository, click once in the first column and the packages are sorted by install status. Mark all packages for removal (if you don't need the package) and try to upgrade again.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Oates - thank you. I uninstalled 'xserver-xorg-video-nouveau' and then was able to upgrade to 10.10 via update-manager. I was worried that I had some weird hardware issue because I was also getting a different error when trying to do a clean install of 10.10 from a disc. Now I'm able to use rnx-easyn1 wireless adapter which I couldn't get to work under 10.04.